# Make a textbox inside the dropdown to focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need to always focus on the textbox

```html
<script src="/scripts/snippet-javascript-console.min.js?v=1"></script>


<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@48,400,0,0">



<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with segmented dropdown button">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Action</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="visually-hidden">Toggle Dropdown</span>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." class="form-control form-control-sm search" />

<p>
This is a text
</p>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding an `onClick` event, and use the `focus()` method on your search field when the dropdown is shown.

So it will look like this :

```js
const dropdownButton = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-toggle")[0];
const inputToFocus = document.getElementsByClassName("search")[0];
dropdownButton.addEventListener('click', event => {
  inputToFocus.focus();
});
```

```html
<script src="/scripts/snippet-javascript-console.min.js?v=1"></script>


<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@48,400,0,0">



<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with segmented dropdown button">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Action</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="visually-hidden">Toggle Dropdown</span>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." class="form-control form-control-sm search" />

<p>
This is a text
</p>

  </div>
</div>

<script>
  
</script>
```

Hope it helped ! Good luck :)